# ggplot does not draw line for all of the levels of categories in the data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, group-by

I used this code to draw the percent of people in poverty in state of Maine. This state has 17 counties. `ggplot` only shows 14 of them:

```
ggplot(data=data_ME, aes(x=Year, y=PersonsinPoverty, group=Countyname, shape=Countyname, colour=URBAN)) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:17)) +               # Set shape of each line manually
    geom_line(aes(linetype=Countyname), size=0.75) +     # Set linetype by County name
    geom_point(size=3, fill="white") +                   # Use larger points, fill with white
    #expand_limits(y=0) +                                # Set y range to include 0
    scale_colour_hue(name="Urban?",                      # Set legend title
                     l=30)  +                            # Use darker colors (lightness=30)
    #scale_linetype_discrete(name="County name") +
    xlab("Year") + ylab("% of People in Poverty") +      # Set axis labels
    ggtitle("Percent of people in poverty in Maine Counties") +     # Set title
    theme_bw() +                                        # Position legend inside
    theme(legend.position="bottom")                     # This must go after theme_bw
```

This is the result that I get:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there are actually 16 counties in Maine (https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Maine), and according to the legend in your image, all of them are being displayed (I also think I can see 17 distinct points, 16 counties + whatever the blank option is at the start at each vertical band). There are no lines for the last four. It's possible that R has run out of line types to use?

Comment: You are right about the number of counties in Maine. But the 17th category is the state average.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. But see my answer below; ggplot has just run out of line types to use. I'm from Maine (Cumberland County), so this was an especially interesting topic for me.

Comment: Nice to hear that and thanks for your help. I clarified my question and you can see it as a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are actually 16 counties in Maine (https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Maine), and according to the legend in your image, all of them are being displayed (I also think I can see 17 distinct points, 16 counties + whatever the blank option is at the start at each vertical band). There are no lines for the last four, because R has run out of line types to use.

To see this behavior, run

```
date <- rep(1:5, each = 20)
val <- rnorm(200)
group <- factor(rep(1:20, times = 5))

dat <- data.frame(date, val, group)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = val, group = group)) + geom_line(aes(lty = group))
```

Note that the first 13 groups get line types, but the next seven do not, just as in your example.

[image: Lines only display for the first 13 groups]

It looks like your image is producing what you intended, there are just too many counties to give each one a unique line type.

Edit: as suggested in a comment, it's quite challenging to discriminate between that many line types, so it's become less useful as a way of distinguishing them.

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than an answer ... it's speculative, and doesn't actually provide a solution ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here and want to do things correctly. I deleted my answer and moved it to a comment, but then undeleted it once I was able to provide evidence that I was right about the missing lines. Is this reasonable as a solution (it explains what's going on in the original post), or should I keep it as a comment?

Comment: that seems great. I was actually thinking about retracting the flag anyway since your answer seemed more correct the more I looked into the question.

Comment: I might also add to your answer that (a) it's almost impossible to distinguish between that many line types anyway and (b) `scale_linetype_discrete(values=c(1:12,1:4))` would serve to rescale line types ...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like to show all of the levels as lines and it does not matter if they are different. My question was that how can I show a line (any line) for the last 4 categories.

Comment: Then maybe just remove the linetype argument in aes()? Or set linetype = URBAN? I played around with some other solutions, but they're not super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help! I found a fix (not necessarily the answer) to my question.

It seems that 'R' only has 13 types of lines. Therefore, I need to remove the line type from my code. I changed the following part in my code:

```
geom_line( size=0.75)+
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: by the way, you still have an "empty" county represented by a circular point in the legend - don't forget to drop empty levels ...

Comment: Thank you Ben! <br/>This was my first experience with StackOverflow and I absolutely enjoyed it.